# How to change the GCC version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I just install a kali-linux， and trying to play with it.

I did use ubuntu before. That cause some problems with different gcc version when I am trying to use some code what I build in my old Ubuntu.

I check the gcc -v; the kali give me
gcc version 6.1.1 20160802(Debian 6.1.1-11)
and ubuntu give me
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)

I am not sure if my code doesn't compile because of this or not. But just want to check.

how can I remove Debian's gcc and switch to ubuntu one?

Comment: Better to try and fix your code. Use the newest compiler.

Comment: First you need to get rid of your current version: `sudo apt-get purge gcc`...then `sudo apt-get install gcc-5.4` ;)

Comment: find real problem and fix code would spend more than two month I guess......

Comment: @Hackman  I did try to remove the old gcc, but when I try  sudo apt-get install gcc-5.4  it unable to locate package gcc-5.4   are there any other name possible?

Comment: @dawenzi098 I have the same exact issue. Any solution anyone?

Answer (score 3):

May be i'm not much familiar with debian. But with Ubuntu, i've followed this and changed the gcc version. May be this will help.
[Change default gcc version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version)

You can use this command to install gcc versions.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.3 gcc-4.4
```

Once installed, you have to update the alternatives with the variant gcc versions. Using

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.3 10
```

You can choose which version of gcc, you can use by this command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Comment: How can I choose the alternative to switch to programmatically, like in a provisioning script?